# XPATH and CSS for Selenium Automation - Help Required

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

I want to Find the XPATH/CSS locator to extract the text from the following structure.
Kindly help.

```
<div class="page-header song-wrap">
<div class="art solo-art">
<div class="meta-info">
<h1 class="page-title">
Zehnaseeb
```

---

I want to give the locator/XPATH so that it can return the text "Zehnaseeb" (In this case)

This did not yield any result,

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/h1")).getText();

Comment: is the h1 tag closed after "Zehnaseeb"?

Comment: also you should specify the code language you are using. c#? java?

Comment: The h1 tag is not closed after Zehnaseeb, The complete TAG IS HERE,1 class="page-title">
Zehnaseeb
<a class="pill star " onclick="Content.toggleFavourites('ZZ4mj40V','hindi', this, $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.song-json').html() ); this.blur(); void(null);" onmousedown="this.blur();" title="Add to Starred Songs">
</h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried [waiting](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for the element,

```
String text = new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.page-header h1.page-title"))).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, I recommend to use "ScrapySharp", it's very nice for parsing HTTML.

https://bitbucket.org/rflechner/scrapysharp/wiki/Home

```
Document htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.loadHtml(driver.PageSource);
var zehnaseebstring = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("h1.page-title").SingleOrDefault().InnerText;
```

this should work.

Comment: I also tried this but dint work, //*[@id='main']/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/h1/text()

Answer (score 0):

I would check all the elements in between to see that the hierarchy is correct, but you could try to simplify by removing some of the elements in between by using descendant `//`

```
//*[@id='main']//h1[@class='page-title']
```

Comment: //*[@id='main']//h1[@class='page-title'] This again reaches the page-Title only but does not get the text if when the code runs, Since the h1 tag is not closed here, I think its kind of difficult to extract the text